# Why doesn't this mock the logging call?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, laravel-5

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong but:

```
class Details {

    public function details($href) {
        $client = new Client();
        $eveLog = new EveLogHandler();

        $response = $client->request('GET', $href);
        $eveLog->requestLog($response, 'eveonline_item_details.log');

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to mock this: `$eveLog->requestLog($response, 'eveonline_item_details.log');`

So I wrote a test:

```
class DetailsTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function getLogMock() {
        return $this->getMockBuilder('EveOnline\Logging\EveLogHandler')
             ->setMethods(['requestLog'])
             ->getMock();
    }

    public function testDetailsDoesNotReturnFalse() {

        $details = new EveOnline\Items\Details();

        $logger = $this->getLogMock();
        $logger->expects($this->exactly(1))
            ->method('requestLog')
            ->with('request', 'request.log');

        $response = $details->details('http://example.com');

        $this->assertNotFalse($response);
    }
}
```

Accept it doesnt mock the method call, instead it freaks out with an error:

```
1) DetailsTest::testDetailsDoesNotReturnFalse
Error: Call to undefined function EveOnline\Logging\storage_path()
```

Now this method: `storage_path` is a laravel method and since this library is out side of laravel, for development purposes, the method doesn't exist, hence me trying to mock the call to: `$eveLog->requestLog($response, 'eveonline_item_details.log');`

Two questions arise from this:

1. First of all why doesn't my test pick up on the fact that I have mocked the method call?
2. When it coms time to test this particular method how do you mock global functions? Laravel has a few of them and I'll need mock out the `storage_path` method.

**Ideas?**

**update**

It should be known that this class gets turned into a laravel facade via a provider class and a facade class that both get registered with laravel allowing me to do something like

```
EveDetails::details()
```

For example. Learn more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

I can post the facade and provider class of that will help.

The only reason the class is instantiated in my ear is because this particular component is being built as a separate installable component of laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `Details::details()` doesn't know that `$eveLog` should be an instance of your mock instead of class `EveLogHandler`. You have to inject the instance of your logger by using [dependency injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html).

The simpliest way to do this is to put it to the constructor:

```
class Details {

    private $eveLog;

    public function __construct($eveLog) {
        $this->eveLog = $eveLog;
    }

    public function details($href) {
        $client = new Client();

        $response = $client->request('GET', $href);
        $this->eveLog->requestLog($response, 'eveonline_item_details.log');

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In your production code you'll have to call:

```
$details = new EveOnline\Items\Details(new EveLogHandler());
```

to inject the real Eventlogger (an instance of class `EveLogHandler`) to the instance of class `Details`.

In your TestCase you'll now have inject your mock:

```
$logger = $this->getLogMock();
$logger->expects($this->exactly(1))
       ->method('requestLog')
       ->with('request', 'request.log');

$details = new EveOnline\Items\Details($logger);
```

Comment: Details cannot have a constructor because it's never instantiated. Is a laravel facade so this class is registered via a provider and turned into a facade allowing me to do something like: 'EveDetails::details()'  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades so your method won't work. Any other way? The only reason it's instantiated here is because I am building this component seperate of larvel to be used like a library.

Comment: Don't you have a possibility to add the dependency "Class Details requires instance of class EveLogHandler" to the [DI-Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container) of your laravel project so that it will be injected automatically? I'm not familiar with Laravel..

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow are you saying that I should have the ability to ass the logger to the DI container? If so then no, why? Because this logger is meant as an internal logger for the library that I'm building. I don't want you to have to set up the logger as well as the classes you want to use, I just want you to set up the classes you want to use and they them selves use the logger to then log out responses as to see above.